# How to programmatically scroll a QPrintPreviewWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll

I've got a `QPrintPreviewWidget`, I update its content programmatically based on user input. The problem when doing so is that the scrollbar stays where it was, while I need it to go back to the top.

I tried using the `scroll` function with a very big number but that didn't do anything. Any suggestion?

**Edit:**

Here is the structure of the dialog in Qt Creator:

[image]

Then I add the `QPrintPreviewWidget` to the `previewWidgetContainter` layout using this code:

```
previewWidget_ = new QPrintPreviewWidget(printer_, this);
previewWidget_->fitToWidth();
ui->previewWidgetContainter->addWidget(previewWidget_);
```

**Edit:**

I followed @tmpearce 's suggestion, but that didn't work. On the `showEvent` I set the current page but it has no effect whatsoever. My code is something like this:

```
qDebug() << "Before" << previewWidget.currentPage();
previewWidget.setCurrentPage(0);
qDebug() << "After" << previewWidget.currentPage();
```

And the output of this is always something like that:

```
Before 15
After 15
```

I also tried setting the page in various other places but the result is always the same. That looks like a bug in `QPrintPreviewWidget` so I'm going to give up for now. Thanks anyway for the suggestions.

Comment: Please can you provide some minimal code allowing people to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Unless mistaken, QPrintPreviewWidget is a widget and does not provide scroll bars. Did you embedd it in a QPrintDialog or other QAbstractScrollBar subclass?

Comment: @menjaraz, I've added some code to show how I add the widget to the dialog.

Comment: @Koying, I didn't embed the widget in a `QAbstractScrollBar`, just added it to a layout. The scrollbar is needed to scroll through the pages so I think it's part of `QPrintPreviewWidget`, but I just don't know how to control it.

Comment: OK. What do you mean by `update its content programmatically`? What do you do exactly? Normally, all you have to do is respond to `paintRequested`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about the specifics of your code, my suggestion would be to explicitly call [this slot:](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/qprintpreviewwidget.html#setCurrentPage) `QPrintPreviewWidget::setCurrentPage(int)`

after changing the contents of the widget.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that (see updated post) but it didn't work. That should be the way to do it though (if QPrintPreviewWidget was working as expected, or when it gets fixed), so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @laurent do any other values for page (like 1 or 2, for example) do anything?